# Outlook automation with Delphi - Queue

Tags: delphi, email, automation, outlook

I currently have the following code:

```
  while not (sqlMailMergeData.Eof) do
  begin

  if sqlMailMergeData.FieldByName('Email').AsString <> '' then
  begin
  Inc(Count);
  {Connect to Outlook}
  MailItem := OpOutlook1.CreateMailItem;
  MailItem.MsgTo := sqlMailMergeData.FieldByName('Email').AsString;
  MailItem.Body := Form48.Memo1.Text;
  MailItem.Subject := Form48.Edit3.Text;
  MailItem.Send;
  end;

  Form34.sqlMailMergeData.next;
  end;
```

However Outlook prompts you to allow ever email with a delay of 5 seconds. Sending after the loop overwrite the same MailItem.

```
  MailItem.Save;
```

Saves all the items to draft without prompting. This is not a bad solution and could be an extra feature but requires more user input to move the items to outbox.

Is there a function to send each mail item to the outbox? or should I consider creating a string of all the email address e.g.

```
MailItem.MsgTo := "example@email.com; example2@email.com"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with outlook, you might consider using outlook redemption[1](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/), this way you can bypass the security prompt and send the mail directly from your code.

Comment: Thanks Tobias but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require additional components. Maybe something within the Delph code which bypasses this security feature.

Answer (score 1):

Then your only option is to do what [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is doing under the hood - use Extended MAPI.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code which works fine for me:

```
Outlook := CreateOleObject ('Outlook.Application');

    // Repet the code below for each mail:
    OutlookMail := Outlook.CreateItem (olMailItem);  // olMailItem = 0;
    OutlookMail.Recipients.Add ('example@email.com').Resolve;
    OutlookMail.Recipients.Add ('example2@email.com').Resolve;
    OutlookMail.Subject := Form48.Edit3.Text;
    OutlookMail.Body := Form48.Memo1.Text;
    OutlookMail.BodyFormat := olFormatHTML;
    // OutlookMail.SendUsingAccount := OutlookAccount;  // If you need to select the acount
    OutlookMail.Send;
```

Comment: This will only work without prompts if you have an up-to-date anti-virus software installed. Otherwise the prompts will still be shown.